# Error on Gitlab fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/xxxx/xxx/file.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, gitlab, certificate, gitlab-ci, gitkraken

i have a problem with Gitlab, when i try to do a push/pull or clone with a remote repo, return this error "fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/xxxx/xxx/file.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403" or when i try to clone a repo

```
$ git clone https://gitlab.com/xxxx/XXXX.git
Cloning into 'XXXX'...
warning: ----------------- SECURITY WARNING ----------------
warning: | TLS certificate verification has been disabled! |
warning: ---------------------------------------------------
warning: HTTPS connections may not be secure. See https://aka.ms/gcm/tlsverify for more information.
warning: ----------------- SECURITY WARNING ----------------
warning: | TLS certificate verification has been disabled! |
warning: ---------------------------------------------------
warning: HTTPS connections may not be secure. See https://aka.ms/gcm/tlsverify for more information.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/xxxx/XXXX.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

This error happens some times and other times it doesn't.

I use Gitkraken, i try to reset credential in Windows's Credential Manager.

Comment: The TLS certificate warnings are worrisome, but not the cause of the 403. HTTP 403 indicates that the credentials are valid, but that the associated account does not have permission to do the requested action (in this case, clone). Are you sure that the gitlab.com account you're using has read permission on that repo?

Comment: Yes, i sure because i have this problem with two pc and they use two different account, I think it is a problem on network, because if they use hotspot it works.  I tried to open some port use git: 80, 443, 9418, 22.